# Finding if a variable has a decimal place / is a decimal number in Lua Corona SDK

Tags: math, sdk, lua, decimal, coronasdk

I'm creating a math application, the question answers are stored in a variable called answer, i need a way to check if the answer has a decimal point in it, so for example say if the question generated is 4 divided by 3, i want to be able to check if the answer will have a decimal in it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [math](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.6) standard library. One way of checking if a number is an integer would be using the floor function:

```
x == math.floor(x)
```

Of course, this assumes x is a number and not a string.

Comment: Wow! Didn't realise it could be so easy!! Thank you!

Comment: @lhf: The floor operation will work but the equality test will fail because it will be comparing a string to a number.

Comment: You're right, of course. Sorry for the noite. I've removed that comment.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the modulus operator

```lua
if x % 1 == 0 then
    -- x does not have decimal point
else
    -- x does have a decimal point
end
```

another option is `modf`

```lua
local integral, fractional = math.modf(x)
if fractional == 0 then
    -- x does not have decimal point
else
    -- x does have a decimal point
end
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you need to check if a number is divisible by others, so just use modulus
(if you don't know, modulus is the remainder of the division)

```
if N % D == 0 then
print("divisible")
else
print("not")
end
```

(this will print "divisible" if N is a multiple of D)